# Trouble with googlevis using Knitr HTML in RStudio 0.98.94

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, googlevis

When using RStudio 0.97, I used to be able to easily knit `googleVis` plots into html output.  However, now using RStudio 0.98.94, it causes an error even for the following Rmd:

````
---
title: "knitr googleVis"
output: html_document
---

```{r, results='asis'}
library('googleVis')
tbl <- gvisTable(data.frame(letters = letters[1:5], number = seq(5)))
print(tbl, 'chart')
```
````

The error message is:

> pandoc.exe: Failed to retrieve https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=displayChartTableID253831656700
>
> InternalIOException getAddrInfo: does not exist (error 11001)
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In if (grepl(" ", path, fixed = TRUE)) path <- utils::shortPathName(path) :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>
> Execution halted

The following is my sessionInfo():

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    > LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
>   [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] googleVis_0.5.4
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] digest_0.6.4     htmltools_0.2.4  RJSONIO_1.0-3    rmarkdown_0.2.49 tools_3.0.2      > yaml_2.1.13

Does anyone have any ideas on fixing this?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[Knitr does not render googleVis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490026/knitr-does-not-render-googlevis) or `devtools::install_github('mages/googleVis')` is work for me.